# Changes on Android String resources not visible

Tags: android

When I change any value on the `string.xml` and I stop and run the app, the changes are not visible, instead the old value is still there.

The only way I found to make the changes in `strings.xml` file visible when running the app is:

1. Add new key/value in `strings.xml`
2. Reference the new key from a fragment for example

So seems like Android Studio is only "building" the `strings.xml` once a new key is added (and referenced!), otherwise it uses always the "old version", even if I remove the `build` folder (of the project and of the resources).

Does anyone faced a similar problem? Any ideas?

Comment: Have you try to rebuild your project ?

Comment: Yes I tried, and just in case I also removed the build folder as I mentioned to be sure Im not using an old build